# How to change vtkTextActor origin from bottom left to top left?

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a text actor in a view that is on the bottom left. `TextActor` doesn't have a `setOrigin` method that I know of. I can't just set the position because it doesn't look great on different viewport sizes.

Should I check the size of the window and update the position whenever the view is resized?

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

```
textActor->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport();
textActor->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetValue(0, 0.9); // Adjust these values as needed
```

The `SetValue` function takes normalized coordinates in the range of [0,1], where (0,0) is the bottom left corner and (1,1) is the top right corner of the viewport.